# ntlm_auth against AD with validation of multiple group membership

Tags: freeradius, ntlm-authentication

I have been trying to set up `freeradius` service for our network devices which would authenticate against Active Directory. I have the authentication working right now. The next piece I am trying to accomplish is to check whether the user is part of a group. Which is quite easy using the paramater "`require-membership-of`" for `ntlm_auth`

The config I have is this:

```
program = "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=DOMAIN --require-membership-of='DOMAIN\NetworkAdmins' --username=%{mschap:User-Name} --password=%{User-Password}"
```

But I cannot find a way to check against 2 or more groups. Is there a way to do it somehow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer: don't use `ntlm_auth` for this, but use the LDAP module instead.*

Group checking via `ntlm_auth` is very basic. (It's actually also better to skip using `ntlm_auth` completely and start to use the direct winbind auth built in to FreeRADIUS: see `winbind_username` and `winbind_domain` in `raddb/mods-available/mschap`.)

To have much better control over group membership checking (including correctly checking nested groups) you should not do it as part of `ntlm_auth` (or winbind auth) at all, but configure and use the `ldap` module.

See `raddb/mods-available/ldap` for all the details. You'll need to create a symlink `raddb/mods-enabled/ldap -> ../mods-available/ldap` to enable it.

With the LDAP module configured you can use the virtual attribute `LDAP-Group` to test to see if the user is in groups, e.g.

```
if (LDAP-Group == "group1" && LDAP-Group == "group2") {
    ...
}
```

If you find that that is still not flexible enough for your configuration, you can use an XLAT expansion to do ad-hoc LDAP queries.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the information.
I am using FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.13, but it seems they dumped completely LDAP module from it. Not sure if they dont support it anymore

So not sure if I have any other options than ntlm_auth

Comment: The LDAP module certainly hasn't been removed. You might need to install another package (e.g. `freeradius-ldap`) if you're using O/S packages.

Comment: Aah didnt notice that you have to install it separately. Thanks, will play with that now